# How to run docker-compose with link all services into one another container ubuntu

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have question for Docker, I have many containers like:

- nginx
- php-fpm
- mysql
- nodejs
- composer
- ...

And I want to setup them by Docker Compose on Windows 10 with "Docker for Windows" application, but I would to bring them into one another container such as "Ubuntu 16.04". So how can I do that?

Thanks so much, guys!

Answer (score 0):

To do that, create a Dockerfile based on "Ubuntu" image and setup all of them manually, same as you would install them on a "normal" machine.

But this is against the purpose, why docker was created for. Image, or more specifically, a container based on the image, is a specialized virtual machine intended to handle one specific service - search for "microservices" term.

Comment: Thanks for reply! About Dockerfile, I had already done that. But I need to setup with Docker Compose. Because I want to environment on Docker and production will be same.

Comment: can you extend your question with the dockerfile and docker-compose.yml that you have? I understand, that you have some "production" environment that is running compose with bunch of services and you want to have, one "dev" container having all of them included, correct?

Comment: Ah, I got it! For example: 
I have some files dockerfile such as: nginx.dockerfile, php-fpm.dockerfile, mysql.dockerfile, ... Do I only need to define their services will be run from a image's Ubuntu, right?

Comment: No. docker-compose is to be executed on the host machine and each service will run, on the host, a container based on the specified image. Although there's a concept of docker-in-docker, where you can run containers inside a container, but it contains a lot of pitfalls you need to be aware of - see http://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/

Comment: No, I don't want to run docker-in-docker. Just like: service nginx run based on ubuntu-16.04, service mysql run based on ubuntu-16.04, ... Or another way like https://stackoverflow.com/a/49730772/6892346

Answer (score 0):

You should be using docker-compose to create and manage multiple services. Ideally there will be a container for each of your components nginx, php-fpm, node, mysql. The container can be linked and accessible to each other over the network.

Comment: That's right. Could be declare "From ubuntu:16.04" based on each files that define for each services? Such as nginx run based on ubuntu 16.04, mysql run based on ubuntu 16.04, ...

Comment: Unless there is a very specific reason, all containers don't need to inherit from ubuntu:16.04. Think of the container as an abstraction. All you should care about is that you get nginx and not really the under lying OS of the container.

Comment: The specific reason for example, I have 4 environments such as: dev, test, staging, production and OS for them was not same. So if I make sure my source code will be run OK on 4 OS. That's reason I want to make 4 virtual servers corresponding
to 4 OS on Docker to test them.

Comment: In that case you are better served using virtual machines than containers. You should consider streamlining all the four environments to the same OS. It'll be futile spending time on fixing bugs that occur only on staging and not production due to an environment difference.

Comment: I think so. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple dockerfiles like one for nodejs another fo angular and another one for database and then you can link all the dockerfiles by creating one docker-compose file like this :

```
version: '2' # specify docker-compose version

# Define the services/containers to be run
services:
  angular: # name of the first service
   build: gamification-frontend # specify the directory of the Dockerfile
    ports:
    - "4200:4200" # specify port forwarding

  express: #name of the second service
    build: gamification-backend # specify the directory of the Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000" #specify ports forwarding
    links:
      - database # link this service to the database service

  database: # name of the third service
    image: redis # specify an image to build container from
```

So these are three different containers 
1. angular 2. express 3. database 
which are linked together. To run these containers use:

```
docker-compose up --build
```